# Why should not one start a glassfish server from root user if the server is located in "user1" directory?

Tags: glassfish

Today, an issue happened. Our company went down. I was trying to start that server. I did it from root. When I do

```
./asadmin list-domains
```

it would show "domainX not running" even though it was running.

A senior colleague told me that I made a MISTAKE by running glassfish servers from root and I need to do it from the user who is the owner of that server.

I didn't understand why. Please explain someone?

Comment: The directory where the binary is located is probably irrelevant. 

Running any command as the correct user is often relevant when that command/service will relies on data in/from the users home directory ( often referred to as `$HOME`  and/or `˜/` )  

Typical  a command service will rely on for example  on the correct environment properties that get set when loging in to that account and/or it will default to writing data to `˜/` and when you run as a different user or root, the programme will look in the wrong home directory or be missing environment  vars